# Struggling to mount on Cent-OS on VMware workstation

Tags: centos, vmware-workstation

This is what I did.

(1) Enabled "Shared" on VMware workstation 10 with a Windows Host's folder.

(2) Extract "vmware-tools-distrib" into my /home/Tom/Download and run "vmware-install.pl"

(3) On terminal "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /home/Tom/Share"

Yet it is complaining "Cannot mount filesystem: No such device"

Please help me and thanks.

Comment: I would just copy the ISO to the VM before mounting it. Much simpler.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Does the VM have access to the internet ?

Comment: Yes, it is NATed in.